# How to implement separator in List by SwiftUI on macOS properly

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui, swiftui-list

It seems there is no default separator in List by using SwiftUI on macOS. So I am using Divider to add by manual. But when I enable multiple line selection, the app will render a white line automatically. And it seems strange that both divider line and white line exist.

Is there a best practice way to implement row separator on macOS by using SwiftUI ? Or can I remove the default white line rendering by selection?

1. add divider
   [image]
2. multi selections with divider
   [image]
3. multi selections without divider
   [image]

```swift
struct WelcomeView: View {
    let contents = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
    @State var selection = Set<String>()

    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selection) {
            Section(header: Text("header")) {
                ForEach(contents, id: \.self) { row in
                    VStack {
                        Text(row)

//                        Divider()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw your code, it is kind of strange, why you are using List and ForEach together? one of them supposed to be there, also you are using Set for a List!?! that is not how should be! Why Set? why not array?

Comment: @swiftPunk I am using List and ForEach together because I want to show some sections  in the list including some headers or footers. And using set for selection because it is specified by List interface. `selection: Binding<Set<SelectionValue>>?`

Comment: I know all what you said, I just wanted give you a general idea, otherwise there is some reason for sure in your codes

Comment: @swiftPunk ok, thank you for you help.

Comment: @morphinewan did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @user1046037 sorry, not yet

Answer (score 3):

In macOS 13 or newer you can now use the listRowSeparator modifier like this:

```
List {
    ForEach(garage.cars) { car in
        Text(car.model)
            .listRowSeparator(.visible)
    }
}
```